# How do I get ${pageContext.request.localName} to return "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" on my local machine?

Tags: jsp, localhost, jstl, jboss7.x, osx-yosemite

I’m running JBoss 7.1.3.Final on Mac Yosemite (Java 6).  How do I get

```
${pageContext.request.localName}
```

to return “localhost”?  Right now it is returning “127.0.0.1”, despite the fact that when I run hostname on my system, I get “localhost”

```
localhost:mydir davea$ hostname
localhost
```

and my /etc/hosts file doesn’t seem to have anything unusual …

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       devbox.example.com
```

Not sure where else I need to look to adjust this setting properly. - Dave

Comment: Have you tried using ${pageContext.request.serverName} ?

Comment: Although that would work for me locally it would screw up our pages in other environments (we run JBoss behind Apache, which is behind a load balacner.  The domain fo the load balacner is not the same as the domain of each server it reaches).